# "rails generate" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When using ruby 2.1.0 (or 2.1.1) and I type `rails g` nothing happens. It simply hangs.
But when I change to 1.9.3, using `rvm use 1.9.3` it works as expected.

How can I debug this? What might be causing this command to hang, only on ruby > 2.0.0?

I have tried reinstalling both rails and ruby!

Comment: Are other ruby scripts impacted or only rails? Have you tried reinstalling ruby ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried reinstalling both rails and ruby! It seems like it only affects rails

Comment: what about use 2.1 ruby again, "rvm use 1.9.3 && rvm use 2.1.0", rails gem exists?

Comment: Yeah, they do. Thank you for the reply. Any other ideas on how I can debug?

Comment: Same with me, I do not have ruby 1.9.3 installed, only 2.1.0. Do I have to install the lower version (again) and then  "rvm use 1.9.3 && rvm use 2.1.0?btw I deleted 1.9.3 after installing 2.1.0

Answer (score 185):

Have you tried to run:

```
spring stop
```

`rails generate` hangs may because *spring* is already running.

see https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/265

Comment: This was very hard to debug because no error was thrown. I had a different issue where it looked like the 'generator' worked in terminal, but no files were actually created. This worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks man! It's really hard to debug since there is no feedback... I think Zeus is a better alternative to Spring.

https://rubygems.org/gems/zeus

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of this and it didn't work for me. Turns out that I had a bad rails file in my /bin folder.

This is what I had:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
require 'bundler/setup'
load Gem.bin_path('rails', 'rails')
```

And I just recreated a new rails app and copied the proper one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

This worked for me!