# rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string but nothing happened

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm just follow << bury on rails tutorial >>  2.2

when i run `$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`, nothing happened, and the terminal just hanged there, I pressed `ctrl+C` to cancle the command, it shows as follow:

> ➜  toy_app git:(master) rails generate scaffold User name: string email: string
>   ^C/Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in gets: 
>   Interrupt from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in verify_server_version
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in run
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in warm_run
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in call
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in call
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in call
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in call
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in run
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in 
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in load'
>       from /Users/duodian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in 
>       from /Users/duodian/Desktop/toy_app/bin/spring:15:in require'
>       from /Users/duodian/Desktop/toy_app/bin/spring:15:in '
>       from bin/rails:3:in load
>       from bin/rails:3:in

i'm using rails 5.0.1 and ruby 2.3.0

Comment: Did you generate any other scaffold, model or controller in this app that worked? There is nothing wrong with your scaffold command.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157426/rails-generate-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a spring problem. Spring is a gem to make Rails load your apps faster. Once you start it it runs in background and quite often, for some reasons, breaks. Way out is simple, though.

Run this and try again to scaffold:

`spring stop`