# Websocket controller not being auto loaded in Rails dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, websocket-rails

So I've been having this problem for sometime since I started working with the `websocket-rails` gem.  Apparently it can't autoload my 'broadcast controller' and is preventing me from running rails commands on the command line.

I used to get around this be commenting out the events file and getting things to load.  Its honestly a crapshoot, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't but lately I havn't been getting it to work, I've been trying to debugg this for a while but honestly I'm stuck.

This only happens in development.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the error stack:

```
/Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:513:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant BroadcastsController, expected /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/app/controllers/broadcasts_controller.rb to define it (LoadError)
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:179:in `constantize_controller'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:172:in `validate_string_target'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:153:in `validate_target'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:102:in `store'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:60:in `subscribe'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/config/events.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:55:in `evaluate'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/event_map.rb:30:in `initialize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:13:in `new'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/dispatcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/connection_manager.rb:32:in `new'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/websocket_rails/connection_manager.rb:32:in `initialize'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/rails/config/routes.rb:3:in `new'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/rails/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `eval_block'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:373:in `draw'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/websocket-rails-3d4bc7cb73e2/lib/rails/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_run_callbacks'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:108:in `run!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:113:in `run!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in reload!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:46:in `tap'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:46:in `block in reload!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:45:in `reload!'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:164:in `serve'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
from /Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from -e:1:in `<main>'`
```

this is what `/Users/matt/Documents/sdcc_grp_buy/app/controllers/broadcasts_controller.rb` looks like:

```ruby
    class BroadcastsController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
        def register_member_to_group
            room = message[:room]
            member_group_id = message[:member_group_id]
            connection = message[:connection]
            member_id = message[:member_id]
            grp = Group.find(room)
            number = grp.member_groups.count
            WebsocketRails["group_#{room}"].trigger('member_registered', {room: room, member_group_id: member_group_id, member_id: member_id, connection_id: connection, :num_of_ppl => number})
        end

        def check_in_member
            room = message[:room]
            member_id = message[:member_id]
            connection = message[:connection]
            member = Member.find(member_id)
            member.checked_in_date = Date.today
            if member.save
                WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('check_in_member', {room: room, member_id: member_id, connection_id: connection })
            end
        end

        def check_out_member
            room = message[:room]
            member_id = message[:member_id]
            connection = message[:connection]
            member = Member.find(member_id)
            member.checked_in_date = Date.today - 25.hours
            if member.save
                WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('check_out_member', {room: room, member_id: member_id, connection_id: connection })
            end
        end

        def delete_member_from_group
            room = message[:room]
            member_group_id = message[:member_group_id]
            connection = message[:connection]
            grp = Group.find(room)
            number = grp.member_groups.count
            WebsocketRails["group_#{room}"].trigger('unregister_member', {room: room, member_group_id: member_group_id, connection_id: connection, :num_of_ppl => number })
        end

        def mark_member_as_covered_for_all_groups
            member_id = message[:member_id]
        end

        def group_updated
            group_id = message[:room]
            count = message[:count]
            total = count.split('/')[1]
            covered = count.split('/')[0]
            if covered == total
                complete = true
            else
                complete = false
            end

            obj = {
                group_id: group_id, 
                count: count,
                complete: complete
            }
            WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('group_updated', obj)
        end

        def cover_member_for_group
            room = message[:group_id]
            member_group_id = message[:member_group_id]
            member_id = MemberGroup.find(message[:member_group_id]).member.id
            connection = message[:connection]
            WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('member_covered', {member_id: member_id, member_group_id: member_group_id, group_id: room, connection_id: connection})
        end

        def someone_typing
            room = message[:room]
            connection = message[:connection]
            WebsocketRails["group_#{room}"].trigger('someone_typing', {room: room, connection_id: connection})
        end

        def deactivate_member
            member = Member.find(message[:member_id])
        member.active = false
        member.sponsor_id = nil
            connection = message[:connection]
        # maybe i need to loop in the JS and not in the controller
        if member.save
                    WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('deactivate_member', { :member_id => member.id,connection_id: connection })
        else
                puts 'ERROR'
        end 
        end


        def activate_member
            member = Member.find(message[:member_id])
        member.active = true
        member.sponsor_id = current_user.id
            connection = message[:connection]
        # maybe i need to loop in the JS and not in the controller
        if member.save
                    WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('activate_member', { :member_id => member.id,connection_id: connection })
        else
                puts 'error'
                puts member.errors.full_messages.join(',')
        end
        end

        def send_chat_message
            type = message[:type]
            room = message[:room]
            message_id = message[:message]
            user_id = current_user.id
            connection = message[:connection]
            if type == 'group'
                WebsocketRails["group_#{room}"].trigger('add_room_message', {room: room, message_id: message_id, user_id: message[:user_id], connection_id: connection})
            else
                WebsocketRails["global"].trigger('add_global_message', {message_id: message_id, user_id: message[:user_id], connection_id: connection})
            end

        end
    end
```

and this is what my events.rb file looks like:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  # You can use this file to map incoming events to controller actions.
  # One event can be mapped to any number of controller actions. The
  # actions will be executed in the order they were subscribed.
  # subscribe :client_connected, 'groups#new_user'
  #
  # Uncomment and edit the next line to handle the client connected event:
  #   subscribe :client_connected, :to => Controller, :with_method => :method_name
  #
  # Here is an example of mapping namespaced events:
  #   namespace :product do
  #     subscribe :new, :to => ProductController, :with_method => :new_product
  #   end
  # namespace :chatroom do
  #   subscribe :create_room, "groups#create_room"
  #   subscribe :update_members, 'groups#update'
  # end

  # namespace :members do
  subscribe :register_member, "broadcasts#register_member_to_group"
  subscribe :unregister, "broadcasts#delete_member_from_group"
  subscribe :cover_member, "broadcasts#cover_member_for_group"
  subscribe :activate_member, "broadcasts#activate_member"
  subscribe :deactivate_member, "broadcasts#deactivate_member"
  subscribe :send_chat_message, "broadcasts#send_chat_message"
  subscribe :someone_typing, "broadcasts#someone_typing"
  subscribe :group_updated, "broadcasts#group_updated"
  subscribe :check_in_member, "broadcasts#check_in_member"
  subscribe :check_out_member, "broadcasts#check_out_member"
  # end
  # The above will handle an event triggered on the client like `product.new`.
end
```

Gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  # git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  #   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  #   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
  # end


  # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
  gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.4'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  # gem 'sqlite3'
  # Use Puma as the app server
  gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
  # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

  # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
  gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
  # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
  # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
  # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
  # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
  # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'omniauth'
  gem 'activerecord-session_store'
  # rails generate active_record:session_migration
  # gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
  gem 'omniauth-facebook'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
  # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
  # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'``
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
  gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
  # gem 'redis-namespace'
  # Use Unicorn as the app server
  # gem 'unicorn'
  # gem 'websocket-rails'
  gem 'react-rails'
  gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.10.5'
  # gem 'webpacker'
  gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'websocket-rails', github: 'recurser/websocket-rails', branch: 'bugfix/388-latest-faye-websocket'
  # gem 'websocket-rails'
  # gem 'websocket-rails', github: 'moaa/websocket-rails', branch: 'threadsocket-rails'

  # gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
  # gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
  # gem 'csv'

  group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'byebug'

    gem 'listen'
    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
  end

  group :production do
    # gem 'websocket-rails' #, github: 'recurser/websocket-rails', branch: 'bugfix/388-latest-faye-websocket'
    gem 'pg'
    # gem 'mysql2'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  end

  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  # gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

development.rb:

```ruby
   Rails.application.configure do
      # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
    config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = true

        # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
      config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = true

      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
      # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
      # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
      config.cache_classes = false

      # Do not eager load code on boot.
      config.eager_load = false

      # Show full error reports.
      config.consider_all_requests_local = true
      config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
      # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
      if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

        config.cache_store = :memory_store
        config.public_file_server.headers = {
          'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
        }
      else
        config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

        config.cache_store = :null_store
      end

      # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

      # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :log

      # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
      config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

      # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
      # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
      # number of complex assets.
      config.assets.debug = false

      # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
      config.assets.quiet = true

      # Raises error for missing translations
      # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

      # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
      # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
      config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      :port => 587,
      :user_name => ENV["SES_SMTP_USERNAME"], #Your SMTP user
      :password => ENV["SES_SMTP_PASSWORD"], #Your SMTP password
      :authentication => :login,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the spring servers was hanging, solved by doing this:

```
spring stop
```

ref: ["rails generate" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157426/rails-generate-not-working)